# python install pip and pandas-data reader on Mac

Tags: python, installation, pip, datareader

I saw some threads suggest to install pip first and then execute pip install panda-reader

Execute in Terminal the following command:
easy_install pip
If you need admin privileges, please execute the following command instead:
sudo easy_install pip
Then, you can proceed with pip-installing packages in Terminal in the universal way.

However it occur syntax error when I run sudo easy_install pip without running anaconda navigator on Mac.

I also tried another method to execute the code in anaconda navigator. However, the code is not running at all.

Attached with two cases screenshots. [anaconda navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLYjg.png)
[sudo easy_install pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh8mS.png)

Greatly appreciate if you can advise the steps to install the pandas-data reader on Mac

Best regards,
Kenneth

I am looking for a solution to install pip install panda-reader that able to perform data analysis in my Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Your screenshot 'anaconda navigator' indicates you aren't following the 'Getting Started' information available at Anaconda distribution documentation. You showed way at the bottom typing 'anaconda-navigator' and then other stuff and not what happens after??! It looks like things were hanging there and you were trying to enter more commands? And then it looks like you are running commands that don't correspond. And, as 0xelight points out, the stuff you show in that screenshot above was wrong because you are using Python 2.7 on your system and definitely don't want to be. That stuff is on ...

Comment: <continued> your system to be used by the Mac operating system (or old versions you had on your mac) and isn't stuff you want to be messing with. You installed the Aanaconda distribution on your  Mac. (Fairly recently from the looks of it by the JupyterLab version info I see.) Because of that you want to be kicking off things from the GUI that is to the left in your screenshot or using commands that begin with conda on the command line to access your environments. Please read more about using the Anaconda distribution.  I suspect on your command line ...

Comment: <continued> **where it recognizes `conda` as a command**,  you can install with pandas-datareader `conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader` , based on [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas-datareader). I'm not familiar enough with easy_install on the Mac to suggest to you where you are going wrong there. But it is actually a bit moot. You have set up your system with the Anaconda distribution, and so you should just use that. You don't want to pollute your system further and confuse yourself, or worse, break things.

Comment: Getting back to my comment, " Please read more about using the Anaconda distribution". I suggest you try other ways to launch things that you installed with it. If you click on the tile for JupyterLab in the Anacaonda GUI I see in your 'anaconda navigator' screenshot, does it open? If so, you can work with the pandas-datareader in there by running `%conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader` inside a running Jupyter notebook and use it. Actually when JupyterLAb starts up, you should be able to also launch a terminal in there where you can run `conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader`.

Comment: <continued> You'll want to ultimately probably read about using environments in Anaconda / conda but since you seem to be having issues with just getting it to work, that can wait. (Try the alternative ways to launch if the command line isn't working is what I am trying to encourage in these last two comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Your error in the screen looks like you have a python that doesn't support variable typing, for example: function thisisafunction(**var:str**):
The problem is that your version of python can't interpret this code because it's too old and doesn't know what is this declaration.

To solve this you need to update your version of python like 3.10 version.
See https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @Oxelight, unless that screenshot with Anaconda is of a super old version (the JupyterLab version being at 3.4.4 actually argues strongly against that), Kenneth should already have software on his machine that isn't based on Python 2.7 . The problem is he is missing that he should be working in Anaconda now when using the terminal. Or use Anaconda Navigator to kick off using the Python ecosystem that came with the Anaconda distribution.